"User is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported" after erasing /etc/group
I login as the only one user in the system
However my /etc/group is empty and not editable.
When I try to access as root, I've got an error

"User is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported" after erasing /etc/group

How to restore access as a root? I found a backup for /etc/group file and want to copy it
this question is different from this one
How do I reset a lost administrative password? as far as the file /etc/group has been errased
Thanks

reboot into rescue mode or use a live session

A slightly different solution to the other suggested Dupe which you say is different: Restore accidentally erased /etc/group file. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
